# Coordinates for specific points calculated in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, coordinates

I have got a layer in **QGIS** that is comprised of connected points which define regions of a country, thus the attribute table consists of 38 regions while the number of nodes in this layer is about 14000. The CRS system is **EPSG:3410**.

I want to do the following. For each regions calculate the rightmost point and then I want **QGIS** to give me the coordinates (XY) of this point. I have looked through many forums but I haven't found the answer to this simple problem.

I can find the x-coordinate of the rightmost point, in the field calculator for the regions layer I type x=xmax($geometry), but I do not understand how to get y coordinate of this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple pyqgis script will do this but the following approach should also work:

- use Extract Nodes to get a point layer of all the vertices.
- add X and Y coordinate columns using $y and $x
- now you can get the y max coordinate for each polygon. Try the Group Stats plugin to get these values for all the polygons.